# Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK helper code not compiling

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

The Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK comes with a few helper classes (not a solution, just .cs files) that reference among other things Microsoft.IdentityModel and System.IdentityModel. The CRM 2011 guide for using these classes can be found here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328228.aspx), no guide for 2013 yet. I am unable to build a .NET 4.5 library project because of the ambiguity of the two different IdentityModel references.

The first error I am getting after following the guide 1:1 is "SecurityToken" could not be found. The new CRM 2013 classes have 
`using System.IdentityModel.Tokens` at the top, so I add a reference to (not mentioned in CRM 2011 link) System.IdentityModel. Then I get 14 errors like this

```
'WSTrustChannelFactory' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannelFactory' and 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory'
```

Has anyone been able to successfuly build and use the helpers for CRM 2013? Was my decision to add the last reference wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to build a project with the WsdlTokenManager class from the SDK samples now and I had to reference both `Microsoft.IdentityModel` and `System.IdentityModel`.

In the code file I had to add these two usings:

```
using WSTrustChannel = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel;
using WSTrustChannelFactory = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannelFactory;
```

So now it compiles, but I have not tried running the code to authenticate a user.

Comment: Yes, had the same finding, but good to have it confirmed. Thanks.